# ContentControl doesn't show Polygon

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, resources, polygon

I'm writing a little program to show states of connections between different `objects` and countries. To be precise those objects are devices and parts `inherited` from the same `class`. If a connection between one of these objects and a country exists, I create a `ConnectionObject` relating to the object and the country. For devices it's easy: since devices can only be connected to a country in one way, the icon would always be the same. But to make it a bit more complicated parts have two connection modes: including and excluding. So you could say a part can be approved or explicitly banned for/from a country. To show this difference, I want to paint different icons in a `ListViewItem` representing the connection `(include = checkmark, exclude = cross, no connection = hide icon)`.
My icons are polygons in a local rescource of the `ListView` presenting the ConnectionObjects. Setting the `polygon` as a resource for a contentcontrol inside a canvas attached to a `ListViewItem` works pretty well for the devices, but not for the parts. So I tried to switch between the `polygons` by creating a `DataTrigger` inside the ContentControl. I thought that would be fine, but even though the space where the icon should be is open (if there is no connection, the item shrinks to the containing label size), there is no `polygon` drawn. I really don't know why. To be true, I'm not a `wpf` specialist and making my first experience with this framework.

Here some Code:

1. the Rescources inside the ListView:

   ```
   <UserControl.Resources>
   <Polygon x:Key="Checkmark"  x:Shared="False"
       Points="0,4 4,8 12,0 12,4 4,12 0,8" Fill="#FF40C858" Stretch="Uniform"/>
   <Polygon x:Key="Crossmark"  x:Shared="False"
       Points="0,0 4,0 6,4 8,0 12,0 9,6 12,12 8,12 6,8 4,12 0,12 3,6" Fill="#FFE52826" Stretch="Uniform"/>
   </UserControl.Resources>
   ```
2. the working canvas of the ListViewItems representing DeviceConnections:

   ```
   <Canvas x:Name="DatCanvas" Width="12" Height="12" Margin="4" Visibility="{Binding IconVisibility}">
       <ContentControl x:Name="DeviceIcon" Content="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0"/>
   </Canvas>
   ```
3. the not working canvas of the ListViewItems representing partConnections:

   ```
   <Canvas x:Name="DatCanvas" Width="12" Height="12" Margin="4" Visibility="{Binding IconVisibility}">
       <ContentControl x:Name="PartIcon" Content="{StaticResource Crossmark}" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0">
               <ContentControl.Style>
                   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                       <Style.Triggers>
                           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConnectionMode}" Value="Include">
                               <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource Checkmark}" />
                       </DataTrigger>
                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConnectionMode}" Value="Exclude">
                           <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource Crossmark}" />
                       </DataTrigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
           </ContentControl.Style>
       </ContentControl>
   </Canvas>
   ```

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`Remove the local value of Content` set on the Canvas directly i.e dont set Content Property in ContentControl node just do

```
 <ContentControl x:Name="PartIcon" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0">
```

then your Style triggers Setter values will be set.

Comment: when I keep the local value the Icon always shows the Checkmark assigned, but when i remove it no icon is shown at all. Only the needed space for the icon seems to be reserved. Is there anything I have to do with dependency properties maybe?

Comment: then your binding in DataTrigger is not correct. can you check are you getting any binding errors in output window ? or you will have to share your whole UI code